# Question About Kadane's Algorithm of Finding Continuous Subarray with Maximum Sum

Tags: algorithm

I checked the solutions used to find continuous subarray with maximum sum using Kadane's algorithm, I don't know why we need global maximum in the code(global_max in the following code).

I think returning local maximum (current_max variable in the following code) after after iterating the whole the array should be sufficient
Could any expert provide some advice? Really appreciate it!

The following is the python code used to find continuous subarray with maximum sum

```py
def find_array(nums):
    current_max = nums[0]
    #I think it should be fine if remove global_max
    global_max = nums[0]
    for i in range(1,len(nums)):

        current_max = max(nums[i],current_max+nums[i])
        if current_max > global_max:
            global_max = current_max
    return global_max
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider case `1 -10`

local maximum will be `-9`. global will be `1`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it:)

Comment: sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, I vote it up and mark it as right, feel free to let me know if I didn't do correctly:)